# Eclipse and GlassFish: remote deployment and debugging

Tags: eclipse, glassfish, remote-debugging

I am currently using Eclipse to develop a fairly straight-forward Java EE dynamic web application. I have just been using Eclipse to deploy the web app to a GlassFish 3.1 server locally running on my dev machine for development and debugging purposes.

So far, so good. But now, I am looking into deploying the app to a remote GF server for further testing.

In Eclipse, I open the "Servers" tab and select the "New->Server" context menu. I enter the IP address of the remote server running GlassFish, but the "New Server" dialog won't let me proceed. Instead, it gives me the error message:

> Remote Server is not secured: It
>   cannot be used remotely...

Some initial research suggests that remote deployment/debugging is currently not supported by Eclipse. Is that what Eclipse is trying to tell me with this weird error message? Surely "Remote deployment/debugging not supported" would be more apt. Am I overlooking something fundamental here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Read http://blogs.oracle.com/quinn/entry/securing_adminstration_in_glassfish_server1

Access to remote servers can only be done if the server has been secured...

Comment: Excellent, that solved everything nicely. That'll teach me not to mess about in unfamiliar waters late at night after a couple of beers.

Comment: The link is broken - is there an alternative link?

Answer (score 0):

You want to make sure you have enabled secure administration. Generally you should do the following:

1. using `./asadmin change-admin-password` command to set a password on the 'admin' user. By default there is none (so when it asks for your current admin password just hit Enter assuming you've never set one)
2. using `./asadmin start-domain` to startup the default 'domain1'
3. using `./asadmin --host localhost --port 4848 enable-secure-admin` will enable remote administration access (which you want) and tell Glassfish to start on the localhost at the default admin port 4848
4. finally use `./asadmin restart-domain` to restart and apply those changes.

You should be able to now access the remote server and manage it via your Eclipse install. This works for Eclipse Luna and Glassfish4 open-source edition. Also note that you need to have a glassfish install on your Local development machine and point to that when it asks for the path to the Glassfish installation when setting up the server in Eclipse Wizard...despite the fact that you are connecting to a remote Glassfish instance. ([See my SO post for more details/screenshots](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28723917/access-remote-glassfish4-server-from-eclipse-luna/28733246#28733246)).

I am adding this because the current accepted answer only points to a link which is typically frowned upon here on SO since links have a tendency to go dead unexpectedly.