# Access Remote Glassfish4 Server from Eclipse Luna

Tags: linux, eclipse, glassfish

I am working on a Mac.

I am running Linux Ubuntu server in a VirtualBox. GlassFish 4 and MySql are already running there. The Linux IP is 10.0.1.12.

On the guest system (Mac) I am running Eclipse Luna. I installed the GlassFish Tools for Eclipse Luna and restarted Eclipse.

Then I wanted to add server for GlassFish4. But Eclipse is asking me for "Server root" and I have no clue what it means! I entered "10.0.1.12:4848/" just as I can access GlassFish from the host system (Mac OS) by a browser. But it just doesn't accept that URL. It seems to expect a local directory path. Here is the dialog box:

[image: What is "Server root"?]

Thanks in advance for any hints!!

Answer (score 2):

You need to install a Glassfish4 Server to your local machine (the one Eclipse is running on) despite the fact that you want to connect to and manage a remote Glassfish server; Eclipse will use some of the files in that local installation to manage the remote Glassfish server. Assuming you already have Glassfish4 installed on a remote machine:

[For example purposes]

- Let's assume the remote Glassfish server is at 192.168.2.7 on default port 4848 for administration and you've set a password for 'admin' user as 'gfish'.
- Let's also assume that your local desktop (development machine running Eclipse Luna) is at 192.168.2.3
- [Download Glassfish4 Open Source edition zip](https://glassfish.java.net/download.html#gfoseTab)
- Unzip the contents to a directory on your local machine: let's say inside of path `/glassfish_server/` you will now have:
  `/glassfish_server/glassfish4/glassfish/` structure

Back in Eclipse:

1. Create a New Server -> Select 'Glassfish4' option
2. Server's Hostname =[remote ip address] // E.G. 192.168.2.7
   Server Name: GlassFish 4 at 192.168.2.7 // get's auto-filled
   [image]
3. [Next] This is the page you were specifically having issue with:
   Set the Root Path to your Local Glassfish Server install directory
   so in this example: `/glassfish_server/glassfish4/glassfish/` should be accepted
   [image]
4. [Next] Now use the credentials and configuration for your remote glassfish server. Run a Ping-Test to test connection.
   [image]

Comment: Dear Brandon, thank you for the resolution! I installed GlassFish4 on the local machine and went through the steps you mentioned. It worked perfectly! It might be interesting to mention that afterwards I removed the server entry in Eclipse and retried to configure it again with the remote server (VirtualBox). This time Eclipse did not ask me for the "Server root". It simply asked for the admin PWD and the port number! Again **BEST THANKS!!**

Answer (score 0):

The server root means the directory where GlassFish is located. This might be, for example, `/opt/glassfish4/glassfish`. Eclipse needs this so that it can look for the `bin/` directory and be able to start/stop the server using the scripts in there.

Comment: Hi Mike! Thanks for your feedback. There is a problem here: Consider the Linux box with GlassFish and MySql (in the VirtualBox) simply as a remote server. You can communicate with it via IP:Port. You don't have access to its directories and definitely cannot start or stop services running on that server.